# Jquery not allow to access constructor or function in the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js class that contains many functions which **proceed_data()** contains Jquery **$.post** function and **callback(function (data))** does not allow to access **preload()** class and **constructor** class in its own.

Please assist me, thanks.

```
    class GridDisplay {
        constructor(current_page){
            this.current_page = current_page;
            this.csrf_token = "ABCDE"
       }
       
       preload(x, y){

             return(x+y);
       }


        proceed_data(){


            $.post("/api/", 
            {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : this.csrf_token, 
            'page_no' : this.current_page,  
            function (data) {

               grid_item = this.preload(data.x, data.y)

            }

            })

        }
```

Comment: use an arrow function for `function (data) {` ... or bind that function to `this`, or use `var _this = this;` outside that callback function and `_this.get_grid_item` inside it - then learn how `this` works :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is that you can't access `this` within the callback?

You probably want to use [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), also called "lambdas" at times, a term sometimes used for anonymous functions.

The main difference between regular function declarations and arrow function expressions is that they don't "reserve" the `this` keyword. It will still point towards the `this` from the previous scope:

```js
function a() {
    console.log(this);
    return () => {
        console.log(this); // Prints the same as above, no matter where this function is called from
    };
}

const obj = { a };
const f = obj.a();
f();
// ^ Prints `obj` twice
```

You can use `data => { ... }` as your callback function so you can still access `this` from the class method.

Alternatively, save `this` in a local variable beforehand, although this is seen as an older pre-arrow-functions technique:

```js
function a() {
    const _this = this;
    console.log(_this);
    return function() {
        console.log(_this); // Prints the same as above, due to the saved variable and function scoping
        console.log(this); // Mind that you don't know what this will print!
    };
}
```